# memory efficient data structures in python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, data-structures

I have a large number of identical dictionaries (identically structured: same keys, different values), which leads to two different memory problems:

- dictionaries are expanded exponentially, so each dictionary could be using up to twice the memory it needs to.
- dictionaries need to record their labels, so each dictionary is storing the keys for that dictionary, which is a significant amount of memory.

What is a good way that I can share the labels (so each label is not stored in the object), and compress the memory?

Comment: Let's start with the obvious question: why do you have a "large number of _identical_ dictionaries"? If they're identical, why do you need more than one?

Comment: sorry, when I say identical dictionaries, I'm referring to the structure, not the contents.  They all have the same keys, but different values.  I'll update the post.

Comment: In this case, build only one dictionary where each item is a list.

Comment: All the same, why do you need several different dictionaries as opposed to a dict where each key points to a list of all the values? To cut to the chase, I suspect an [XY issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I want to know what X led you to thinking about this Y.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:  That would be less than ideal.  The removal of an element from the middle of the list (which would happen frequently) would cause problems.

Comment: @AndrewSpott What kinds of problems? Perhaps the problem is not that you need multiple dicts with shared keys but actually something more efficient than a list for certain types of operations for storing the values?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist:  yes, that would possibly solve the issue, but leads to three different problems:  1.  I'm generating these data structures out of a file.  I would like to do this lazily, because otherwise I need to store two copies of everything:  1 in the file in memory, and 1 in the new data structure that I have put the values in.  2.  these are not all in the same data structure.  There are multiple lists of these dictionaries.  3.  removing values from a long list is O(n), and that will need to be done often.  A data oriented design is much less flexible than my current design.

Comment: I have a similar task and so far I use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s to avoid having the key names stored with each object. My other idea was what @CasimiretHippolyte said: Have one class instance which holds a list (actually a binary [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in my case) for each element. However, this made the whole thing much less flexible indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be offer the following solution to the problem based on the [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/) library:

```
pip install recordclass

>>> from recordclass import make_dataclass
```

For given set of labels you create a class:

```
>>> DataCls = make_dataclass('DataCls', 'first second third')
>>> data = DataCls(first="red", second="green", third="blue")
>>> print(data)
DataCls(first="red", second="green", third="blue")
>>> print('Memory size:', sys.getsizeof(data), 'bytes')
Memory size: 40 bytes
```

It fast and takes minimum memory. Suitable for creating millions of instances.

The downside: it's C-extension and not in standard library. But available on pypi.

**Addition:** Starting `recordclass` 0.15 version there is an option `fast_new` for faster instance creation:

```
>>> DataCls = make_dataclass('DataCls', 'first second third', fast_new=True)
```

If one don't need keyword arguments then instance creation will be accelerated twice. Starting 0.22 this is default behavior and option `fast_new=True`can be omitted.

P.S.: the author of the recordclass library is here.